# How do I get the app icon to show on Xcode 9 simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode

I filled the app icon with images that fit the size requirements and then when I build the app there is not app icon. I tried on an ipad and iphone but there is still nothing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show us what you have actually done. We can't help you fix what we can't see.

Comment: @rmaddy I added pictures

Comment: Have you set that icon set to be app's icon set on the Info tab of your target in Xcode?

Comment: @rmaddy I didn't, how do you set the target?

Comment: As I stated, on the General tab (not the Info tab as I mentioned earlier) of your target. Look at the "App Icons Source" setting.

Comment: @rmaddy Can you be more specific? I don't know where the app icons source is

Comment: Select your app's target. Go to the General Tab.

Comment: This was the issue. You figued it out @rmaddy!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rmaddy found that the error is I didn't set the app icon source in the general tab. Doing this solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Create a high-resolution image and using this site [makeappicon](https://makeappicon.com/ios8icon) it will generate all sizes for you ( supply your mail and the photo) and you'll receive them  , then open **AppIcon** set in **Assets.xcassets** and drag each image according to it's size

Comment: I did that but than after doing that and building the app the icon doesn't appear

Comment: verify every device size has the correct image size when you drag

Comment: I did. It would give me a warning otherwise

Comment: look to this https://github.com/ShKhan9/MyAddresses , run it and do exactly as it's Assets